# Are pixels machine numbers?

Tags: image, machine-precision

*Mathematica* allows one to work with the information that is behind a photo. For example, the command ImageData generates a list containing the “pixels” (which will it be a number from $0$ to $1$ if no options are added) that are present in the photo.

Although, from a specific photo I could verify that each number is a machine number. But I want to know more than that. I want to know that if, for all photos, those numbers will be machine numbers.

I trie dot search at Wolfram website but didn’t find anything about that. So can someone tell me if the pixels in a photo will be machine numbers?

Thank you for your attention!

Comment: It says in the docs: _`ImageData[image,Automatic]` is equivalent to `ImageData[image,ImageType[image]]`_ so if your image is a `"Bit"` image (black and white) it may not necessarially be a machine number but integers 0 or 1.

Comment: Oh I see! I was just checking that right now. But if i choose “Real32” or “Real64” I will get machine numbers for sure, right? I checked with “Byte” and “Bit16” and I got intergers

Comment: Yes try `ImageData[Binarize[RandomImage[]], "Real64"][[1, 1]] // MachineNumberQ` - even though the `Binarize[RandomImage[]]` is a `"Bit"` image, the `ImageData` with `"Real32"` or `"Real64"` gives you a machine-number image.

Comment: `ImageData can return data of different types. However, with `ImageAdjust` you can convert all data to real valued data in the range 0..1